# How to connect Lubuntu to Windows EPSON L210 Printer

Tags: samba, printer

I have two computers. The first one has windows and is connected to the printer. The second one has Lubuntu 14.04 which is connected in the same network as the Windows computer. I've installed the drivers for the EPSON L210 for Linux . But I'm unable to connect to the printer. When I run this command:

```
sudo smbclient -L //192.168.254.100/ -U user -W workgroup
```

Note that the workgroup name is WORKGROUP and the network IP addressof the windows computer is 192.168.254.100. The output gives this:

```
WARNING: The "syslog" option is deprecated
Enter user's password: 
Domain=[DESKTOP-PKHL8SP] OS=[Windows 10 Home Single Language 15063] Server=[Windows 10 Home Single Language 6.3]

Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
ADMIN$          Disk      Remote Admin
C$              Disk      Default share
E$              Disk      Default share
EPSON L210 Series (Copy 2) Printer   EPSON L210 Series (Copy 2)
IPC$            IPC       Remote IPC
print$          Disk      Printer Drivers
Users           Disk      
Connection to 192.168.254.100 failed (Error NT_STATUS_RESOURCE_NAME_NOT_FOUND)
NetBIOS over TCP disabled -- no workgroup available
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at CUPS rather than using smbclient.